# Oracle Solaris 11, ipnat - rdr not working with remote destinations

Tags: zones, solaris-11, nat

I'm trying to reverse proxy traffic coming in on port 8100 at one machine to another. The receiving host is an oracle exclusive zone as is the destination machine.

On the incoming zone I have configure ipnat (/etc/ipf/ipnat.conf) like this.

rdr net0 192.168.0.22 port 8100 -> 192.168.0.23 port 8100

Unfortunately all I'm getting when I try to connect to 192.168.0.22:8100 from a 3rd machine is Connection refused.

The following does work however:

rdr net0 192.168.0.22 port 80 -> 192.168.0.22 port 8080

What else do I need to configure?